# What happend to Walt's Aztek at the end of Breaking Bad season 4?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

I think one of the lesser praised characters in Breaking Bad was the Aztek walt drove the first 4 seasons. It seemed like a very purposeful bit of 'casting'.

That said, what happened to it? The final episode of Season 4 had Walt driving a small white 2-door at the end. Did I miss an important plot point involving the Aztek?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you remember, Walt drove Hank to the "Industrial Laundry" that Hank had sussed out as consuming way-y-y too much energy and had these industrial air filtration systems from Germany. So he had a suspicion it was housing the meth lab - WHICH IT WAS.

Walt insinuated himself into driving him, using his Aztek to get them there, and getting more and more nervous as they approached. He pretended to be lost as they approached, missed the driveway, then passed the facility, requiring him to U-turn. He does this intentionally right into an oncoming car and BAM! totals the Aztek.

So, Hank doesn't get into the laundry because he stays with Walt, who's all-too-flustered from causing an "accident". Also, we see Hank later in a neck brace, presumably injured in the "accident"; maybe there was an ambulance at the scene (I don't remember it)?

All this happens in the episode *Crawlspace*, the one where Walt finds most of the money missing, because Skyler gave it to Ted to pay the IRS.

Comment: I completely forgot about the accident! That makes perfect sense now. Hopefully the Aztek will be back next season!

Comment: @DA. it did return...then was promptly sold for $50 or $100 (forgot).

Comment: The accident is mentioned again during Hank's tirade when he confronts and beats Walt after figuring out that Walt is Heisenberg. This happens in episode S5E09 - Blood Money. "Son of a bitch! You drove into TRAFFIC to keep me from that laundry!"